# Benchmark a USB host transfer speed with Busybox

Tags: usb-drive, busybox, benchmark

I want to benchmark a USB host on my custom machine. It has Busybox V1.20.2. From google, I see that it can be done using dd command.

For testing, i copy blender.exe (76MB) to the home folder in machine. Then I plug in USB thumbdrive, mounted it at /mnt, then I typed:

```
dd if=/home/blender.exe of=/mnt/blender.exe bs=64k count=1024
```

The operation works but at the end there is no indication of speed transfer report. It just shows:

```
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
```

I checked the file has been copied successfully into thumbdrive. I suspect that it is the version of dd boxed into the busybox that is old one.

Is there any other way to check the transfer speed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `time` command to measure how long the transfer took, then use a calculator to calculate the transfer rate.